# How to add custom attributes in openLdap through phpldapserver

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have been trying to add attributes like for example "hobby" or like "height" of a person but not able to add . I can only add predefined attributes.

Is there any way to add custom attributes in my ldap server or like define a new object where I can specify my own custom objects. Please help me with all steps if available.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add arbitrary attributes to an entry over LDAP.
You must extend the schema on the server first, which is an administrative action. How to do this is pretty well documented in OpenLDAP's manuals.